# How to default HTTP request to servername followed by path in JMeter

Tags: apache, csv, url, testing, jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and am having trouble figuring out how to get my default URL to be what I want it to be.  Right now, I've added an `HTTP Request Defaults`config element to my test plan.   In the Web Server box I have a url of the following format:

```
testproject.company.com
```

What I actually want the default URL to be is

```
testproject.company.com/test
```

The first thing I tried was setting the `Server Name or IP` to `testproject.company.com/test`, but this gave me an error

> java.net.UnknownHostException: testproject.company.com/test

Next, I set `Server Name or IP` back to `testproject.company.com` and filled in the `Path` box in the HTTP Request section with

```
/test
```

This does not cause any errors, but all of my tests fail because it is simply using `testproject.company.com` as the default URL.

---

I am also using a `Project Files` config, and within the Configure the CSV Data Source section, in the `Filename` box, have the path to a .csv file.  The .csv file has the following contents:

```
testproject.company.com/test/,username@testproject.train,10,true,WIN
```

---

What's preventing JMeter from adding `/test` to the default URL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to a misunderstanding of the `Path` field under the HTTP Request Defaults section. It appears that the path in that section will only be used for tests where a path is not defined.  So instead of adding the path from the test to the default path, it simply replaces it. Because of this,  you have to manually add the path to each test that specifies a path.

If anyone knows of a better way to do this, let me know!

Comment: Thanks for that update... Its odd though, and lessens the value of the Defaults. It should of course be default and that the Samplers build upon.

Answer (score 11):

Use userdefined variables

Declare the "/test" as PATHVARIABLE in a user defined variable.

In each request append the variable to the path 
${PATHVARIABLE}/yourUrl

Answer (score 1):

Add **"HTTP Sampler"** under **Thread group**. In **HTTP Request Defaults** define **Server IP** as **testproject.company.com** and in **HTTP Sampler** define **"/test"** as **Path**.Leave the **Server Name or IP** field blank.

Thanks

Comment: Where can I find HTTP Sampler?

Comment: I already have many HTTP requests, I was hoping there was a way to not have to add `/test` to every single request

Comment: HTTP Request is the HTTP Sampler

Comment: Set "/test" as **Path** in "HTTP Request Default" and set Server IP as "testproject.company.com"

Comment: I did that, but it would only set that as the default path for HTTP Requests that don't have a path. What I would like is that all requests start with `testproject.company.com/test`, then the path in the HTTP request is added onto that

Comment: If you use "/test" as Path in "HTTP Request Default" and set Server IP as "testproject.company.com" all request will start with **testproject.company.com/test**.Then just set rest extension in "Path" in HTTp request. then the path in the HTTP request will add onto that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111891/discussion-between-adnan-and-tibsar).

Answer (score 0):

> The first thing I tried was setting the Server Name or IP to
>   testproject.company.com/test, but this gave me an error
>
> `java.net.UnknownHostException: testproject.company.com/test`

It appears that this error is given depending on which "implementation" you are using for the HTTP Request sampler.

Setting the implementation to anything other than 'Java' (e.g. HttpClient4) solved this problem for me.